# I have a problem with axios and routes into vuejs

Tags: vue.js, routes, axios

I have the following situation:

I'm editing a place, it's route is http://localhost/place/add/47 by example.
I'm using this component for add a new place and edit a place. When I'm editing a place I load some images that I can delete. Here is the code for delete an image

```js
                this.$swal.fire({
                    title: 'Está seguro?',
                    text: "Realmente desea eliminar la imagen",
                    type: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Borrar'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.value) {
                        axios.delete('image-delete/'+id)
                            .then(response => {
                                this.$swal.fire('Imagen eliminada correctamente');
                               
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                this.$swal.fire({
                                    type: 'error',
                                    title: 'Error',
                                    text: 'Ocurrio un error!',
                                });
                            });
                    }
                })
```

But, really, when I'm trying to delete an image the request(url) I'm getting is http://localhost/place/add/image-delete/65.

I want to go to http://localhost/place/image-delete/65.

I think that this situation is because I'm into place/add route.

Is there any way to eliminate add part or get the parent route from vue?

here is my route code.

```js
{
        path: '/excursion', component: require('./components/excursiones/backend/ExcursionBackendComponent').default,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ExcursionList },
            {
                path: 'add/:id?',
                name: 'excursionAdd',
                component: ExcursionAdd
            },
            {
                path: 'list',
                component: ExcursionList
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: You seem to have architected a system with a frontend + backend in the same root uri namespace. Normally you would have localhost/api/xxxx and you would configure axios to use /api/ as the base uri, then in your .delete it would be ('/place/image-delete') -> localhost/api/place/image-delete. In your case, you've got this mixture of view routes, and api routes all in the same place. How does VueJS know what to do with place/image-delete/65 for example? Does a request using Postman work for that (I would assume not)

Comment: I have the key of the problem, when I put a route like this: 'place/add' vue take the route that I have in the url, ex: localhost/place/place/add/... but when I put the route like this: '/place..' vue take the root of the route part. ex: localhost/place..... so the key is the character /.